# How can I get a widget to display based on a default valuem which is normally displayed through postback after a selectedindexchanged?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms, postback

I am working on a site for internal company use, the dashboard page of my site has several widgets on it. One widget is meant to display payroll information for the managers to look at. This payroll widget has a dropdown list, which is populated based on user roles. A user then selects an option in the dropdown list, and with an auto-post back the panel within the widget displays an overview of payroll information for that store selection.

Here is my aspx as a clear visual aide to what I am referring to:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelPayroll" runat="server">
                    <triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlPayrollStores" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
                    </triggers>
                    <contenttemplate>
                        <div class="dragbox-content">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLabelOverTime" runat="server" Text="Total Overtime Hours: " Width="350px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalOvertime" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLabelHoliday" runat="server" Text="Total Holiday: " Width="350px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalHoliday" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLabelVacation" runat="server" Text="Total Vacation: " Width="350px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalVacation" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lbllableTotalHours" runat="server" Text="Total Hours: " Width="350px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalStoreHours" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLabelPay" runat="server" Text="Total Pay: " Width="350px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalPay" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </contenttemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My SelectedIndexChanged method is a switch statement which calls a version of a payroll() method depending on the selected value, which makes calls to stored procedures and inserts resulting data into the panel through variables. I will not include any of this code as it is not relevant and is working just fine. Once my dashboard loads, and I select a value from the dropdown, the page posts back and the information displays just fine.

**What I am trying to do:**  Have the dropdown defaulted to a specific value depending on the user role (in addition to the current base functionality of being able to select through values) and have the pages original load include the information being displayed in the widget corresponding with that defaulted value. I have thus far been able to set the defaulted value in the drop down per a user role, but I am having problems getting the information to display.

**What I have tried:** I have tried calling the proper payroll() method which makes the calls to the database right after I have defaulted the selected value of the dropdown. Through debugging I see that in this case it doesn't get past the condition for the stored procedure call for some reason. I have also tried creating a second selectedIndexChanged method with no parameters as opposed to (object sender, EventArgs e) and also manually calling that within my .cs in the isUserInRole condition right after I set the selectedvalue of the drop down. Finally, I tried using Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "0;URL=Dashboard.aspx"); in several places in my cs but that obviously just creates and endless loop of refreshing the page.

So, thank you for reading this far. ANY ideas or even suggestions on different perspectives to approach this from would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the posted code - you are most likely setting the `SelectedValue` and calling the payroll() method before you databind the `DropDownList` (so it's still `null`).

Comment: So you are saying that because I am bypassing the usual selectedindexchanged triggered by the aspx, I need to databind my DropDownList? I just tried calling the dataBind() method on the DropDownList right after I set the SelectedValue within the method where I check what role a user is in and populate the dropdownlist depending. I am just testing it here to see if I can first get the info to display automatically for one of the user roles. --Let me know if it would help you if I posted some of my code on the cs side

Comment: @LeoStotch - First off, `SelectedIndexChanged` is triggered only on postbacks, not on the first page load as well (so you need to call it manually then). Secondly, if you set the `SelectedValue` before databinding the `DropDownList`, it is cached until you do, but returns `null` until you actually do it (unless you are adding `ListItems` manually). And posting code **always** helps, you shouldn't even be asking that.

Comment: Yes, the List items are being added manually. Manually calling SelectedIndexChanged within the pageload solved my problem! I was previously confused with how the postbacks work but through trying to figure this out and you pushing me in the right direction I have a much better understanding now, so thank you!